# SQL query optimalization: removing the inner select

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Does someone know how I could change this query to a query without the innerselect?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM products p
WHERE prod_list_price < 1.15 * (SELECT avg(unit_cost)
  FROM costs c
  WHERE c.prod_id = p.prod_id);
```

The above one returns a count of all products matching the criteria and I've tried to change it myself but it does not return the same:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (PRODUCTS p inner join COSTS c
on p.prod_id = c.prod_id)
group by p.prod_list_price
HAVING AVG(c.unit_cost) * 1.15 > p.prod_list_price;
```

It won't let me group by p.prod_id what I actually want. 
And it needs the group by because of the having...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with "innerselect"?

Anyway, one could assume that `p.prod_id` is a key in `products`, in which case this should also work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT p.prod_id,  p.prod_list_price, avg(c.unit_cost) avg_cost
  FROM products p inner join costs c
   ON c.prod_id = p.prod_id
  GROUP BY p.prod_id, p.prod_list_price
) 
WHERE prod_list_price < 1.15 * avg_cost
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this with a `join` and aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM products p join
     (select c.prod_id, avg(unit_cost) as avgcost
      from costs c
      group by c.prod_id
     ) c
     on c.prod_id = p.prod_id
WHERE p.prod_list_price < 1.15 * c.avgcost
```

Oracle has a pretty good optimizer though, so I'm not sure that it will result in a more efficient execution plan.  You will have to look at the plan in order to see.

Comment: It works, but it's a bit slower. But thank you for your answer. P.S. Where can I find the execution plan?

Comment: Never mind. I was looking at wrong thing, I've found the execution plan.